# How to train Pascal parts data set using tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to use [this dataset](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~xianjie.chen/pascal_part_dataset/pascal_part.html) . On extracting the file , I can see that the files are of .m(matlab files) format. How do I train such a dataset using tensorflow? I am new to tensorflow and hence need some help.
Do I have to create anything manually(I get a hunch that I obviously do)? If so, how?

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

any data-set can be converted into Object detection API input format using [convert_to_tfrecord](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py). Then just run the training using the tfrecords file as input data-set.

Comment: I don't think that's the case because it can be clearly seen that https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/create_pascal_tf_record.py takes xml data as input

Comment: Minor modifications of the convert to tfrecord file is required